# How to move data for GnuCash from one computer to another?

Tags: gnucash

I am moving from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I downloaded GnuCash and moved the following from the Windows 7 to Windows 10:

```
from .../user/-me- to .../user/-me-  (The same user name)
'.gconf
.gconfd
.gnome2
.gnome2_private
.gnucash'
```

When I open GnuCash, I get a blank Window that says "Unsaved book"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do a “File -> Open” and to go to the file in `documents/gnucash/` folder. The files are in the form of `id123.gnucash`. Where id is your `id`, 123 is a date/time stamp, and the `.gnucash` as the extension.

There are serval in the folder, so pick the one with the latest date.

Mine was:

```
Documents and Settings/Username/gnucash/CRL.20210416134641.gnucash
```

Answer (score 1):

#### When I open GnuCash, I get a blank Window that says "Unsaved book"?

You have only copied your settings. You need to copy the data as well.

> Application Settings Locations - `Documents and Settings/Username/.gconf/apps/gnucash`
>
> Saved Reports Locations - `Documents and Settings/Username/.gnucash`
>
> Online Banking Settings Locations - `Documents and Settings/Username/.aqbanking`

Source: [2.7. Migrating GnuCash data](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.4/C/gnucash-guide/basics-migrate-settings.html)

Comment: I copied the Documents folder over before, so the data, I think, should be there.  There is a gnucash folder there with a lot of files.  Both the .gconf and gnucash folders have data(files) in them.  I do not need the .aqbanking folder.  thanks Cliff